# Laravel Mix with Bootstrap 4

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-8, laravel-mix

I have been learning Laravel (8) and have enjoyed working with tailwindcss. That said there are some things I still wish to use Bootstrap for. I am having trouble locating documentation on how to set up bootstrap with laravel mix in laravel 8. More specifically, in the `resources/css/app.css` file we put the following for tailwind:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

but Im not sure what would go here for bootstrap.

I noticed older versions of laravel used `php artisan ui bootstrap` but that is not available in Laravel 8 from what I have seen.

Answer (score 15):

Run: `npm install --save-dev bootstrap jquery popper.js`

How your `webpack.mix.js` should look:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

How your `app.scss` should look:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

How your `app.js` should look:

```js
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.Popper = require('popper.js');
require('bootstrap');
```

This is how you could use generated files in your `.blade.php` files:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" type="text/css">
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

If you want to customize Bootstrap, copy `node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss` to `resources/sass/_variables.scss`, change variables you want and change your `app.scss` to:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import 'variables';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

You have some helpful documentation on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/

Laracasts is also quite helpful.

Answer (score 6):

use this steps

```
npm install bootstrap
npm install @popperjs/core
npm install sass@^1.32
npm install sass-loader
```

For Bootstrap Sass files, let's create the “scss” folder in /resources and then a new app.scss file in /resources/scss/. Then insert the following line to the /ressources/scss/app.scss file

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

For Bootstrap JavaScript, insert the following line to the /resources/js/app.js file :

```
import "bootstrap";
```

To compile Bootstrap JavaScript and Sass files with Laravel Mix, you need to edit the /webpack.mix.js file as follows:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass("resources/scss/app.scss", "public/css");
```

now you can run you command

```
npm run dev
```

Now that we have the /public/css/app.css and /public/js/app.js files with Bootstrap included, we can include them on a page (template Blade) via Laravel's asset helper () to use the Bootstrap components

On your Head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
```

On your footer

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

now i think he will work enjoy

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be available in Laravel v8.24.0 though.

**Be aware that doing this procedure do regenerate the webpack.mix.js.**

Steps are:

- install laravel ui: `composer require laravel/ui`
- generate scaffolding: `php artisan ui bootstrap`
- optionnaly generate the same for auth: `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth`
- make npm install required packages: `npm install`
- compile assets: `npm run dev` or `npm run production` (for development or for production)

Then make sure to have the following in your blade templates:

```html
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I only created a project but before I didn't install the laravel ui with bootstrap.. Use sass-loader v.10. With sass-loader 11 there is problems